# Microsoft Edge - High CPU Usage

Tags: cpu, microsoft-edge

Microsoft Edge has abnormally high CPU Usage on my computer, just upgraded to Windows 10. When I open cnn.com in it, it consumes about 50% of my CPU even after the page loads, for a SINGLE tab. When I open two to three more tabs, the browser is basically unusable. However, when I load the same page in IE with Tracking Protection on, it consumes negligible CPU. My machine is a laptop with Intel Dual-Core T4500 2.3 GHz.

Is the problem in my Windows 10 installation, or is because the browser is terrible?

Comment: Does it still happen if you try other sites? It doesn't reach 50% for me but it still sits around 30% even after the page loads. It could be Flash Player, try [disabling it in Edge](http://techhelpkb.com/how-to-disable-flash-player-in-microsoft-edge/) and see if anything changes.

Comment: Yes, when I open multimedia-heavy sites, the CPU usage is very heavy. It is not Flash Player though, I use it to play flash games without problems.

Comment: Well over a year later and I don't think Edge is any better in terms of CPU usage on many sites. In fact, I think it's getting worse. It's a sad day when using eBay on quad core AMD CPU with 8GB RAM is unusable with Edge. It's a fundamental design flaw with the program IMO

Comment: For the record I have a similar issue.  However for me, Edge used to be fine, it wasnt until the Anniversary Update that I started to notice significant performance problems.  Edge runs fine for about 3 minutes, then pages start to load slowly, then sometimes become unresponsive, then the fans start to kick up in my device, and then im using task manager to kill the process.  Its a shame because i really want to use edge, but at this time i simply cant.

Comment: Another few years go by and I'm still seeing this problem, which I have also observed since Edge cam out.  I'm shocked to see a single Edge window with no page open at all consuming 100% of one core!  The only conclusion anyone can draw is Edge is very poorly designed and supported.

Comment: I generally see inactive Edge pages using 10-20% of the CPU, per page.  With a bunch of tabs it's game over for the rest of the system.

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered it yourself although the browser isn't totally crap but the underlying engine has some very obvious design flaws which causes it to use far more CPU cycles and RAM than other browsers. Chrome isn't a frugal program when it comes to RAM but it doesn't have this CPU overload flaw.

The fix will have to be with the developers rewriting the effected code...

Comment: And boy have they "fixed" it by dumping the Edge rendering engine and announcing they are using Chromium...  I don't think anyone saw that coming!